# What is the induced topology of Cantor set?

Tags: general-topology

If we denote $C$ as the Cantor ternary set, obtained by iteratively deleting the middle one-third of each interval starting from $[0,1]$, then $C=\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{3^n}\mid a_n\in\{0,2\}\}$.

The topology on $C$ is the topology induced from $[0,1]$, which is induced by the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Denote the induced topology on $C$ by $T_c$.

Then $T_c=\{U\cap C\mid U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}\}$.

Clearly $C\cap (-9,82)=C$, so $C\in T_c$.
Also $C\cap (1/3,2/3)=\emptyset$, so $\emptyset\in T_c$.
It's also easy to check that every finite intersection of open sets in $C$ is also an open set in $C$.

But I can't figure out why any arbitrary union of open sets in $C$ is open in $C$.
Also what is the basis of $T_c$?

Comment: The topology "induced" in this way is just called the subspace topology and can be found, e.g., at the first link under the "Related" sidebar for your question as pertains to the Cantor set $C \subset [0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. [**Direct link**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59272).

Comment: Hint $(A \cap C) \cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B)\cap C$, i.e. $\cap$ is distributive over $\cup$ (and $\cup$ is also distributive over $\cap$).

Comment: Let $\{O_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ be a class of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\{O_{\alpha}\cap C\}_{\alpha \in I}$ is a class of open sets in $C$, and  any class of open sets in $C$ will be this form. Now consider $O':=\cup_{\alpha\in I}(O_{\alpha}\cap C)=(\cup_{\alpha\in I}O_{\alpha})\cap C$. Since $O_{\mathbb{R}}:=\cup_{\alpha\in I}O_{\alpha}$ is an union of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, which is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. So $O'=O_{\mathbb{R}}\cap C$, which is an open set in $C$ by definition.